# Docker-Compose Run as Host User

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a container that runs an ASP.net process in a Windows container via Docker Compose. I need to run this process in the container as my domain account - ie my account on the host machine.  I am struggling to find the correct commands.

```
version: '3'
services:
    test-impersonation:
        image: "test-impersonation:1.0"
        user: "USER=${USER}"
        ports:
            - "3001:3001"
```

Can anyone help?

Cheers
KH

Comment: Can you approach this differently and give the container uid the necessary permissions?

Comment: The process needs to use my account to connect to a SQL instance, so I'm not sure the above would work